# Switching Language Input on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, laptop, language

So I looked up how to change the language using 'Left Alt+Shift', but when I do it stays English and doesn't switch until I click the language change tab in the computer taskbar, so it gets really annoying. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Hotkey for language switching was somehow changed away from Left Alt + Shift to something else.

You could check what the Hotkey is set for, by doing as follows:

- Right-click on the **Language Bar** in your Windows 8.1 taskbar, and select **Settings**
- The Language Control Panel applet will open. Select **Advanced Settings** from the left side
- Under Switching option methods, click on the **Change language bar hot keys**
- In the **Text Services and Input Languages** box, select the **Advanced Key Settings** tab. Select the Action (you probably want to look on **Between input languages**) and then on the Change Key Sequence button
- Set the Hotkey you want to use. Click OK, Apply and Exit.

You should now be able to use the set Hotkey to change the input language.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 8 and higher `Windows + Space` is the default key combination to switch between languages.